# Combining background image and background colour with transparent element

Tags: css, background-image, background-color, transparent, frontend

I'm having a bit of an issue with some CSS.

In the main content section I am using a background image, within that image is a transparent element which shows the background below it. This is fine and does what I want.

The issue is that I want to also specify a background colour so that if the content is longer than the image then the background continues. However, if I add a colour to the background, I lose the transparent part of the background image.

Is there a way to use both a transparent background and a solid colour on the same div but have the colour position be lower than the transparent part?

Here is the background with the transparent element showing the background underneath:

[image]

And I'm trying to avoid this, the sidebar is longer than the main content so the background ends early:

[image]

Comment: My first instinct would be to say no.

If an element has a BG colour it'll always be there, even showing up through gaps in the BG image.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that would be the case - Thanks Adrian.

Comment: @Moak Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/zMCdG/2 - It's a simple two column layout - I've had to simplify the code for the sake of the demo.

Comment: Wait a sec, the background that ends early, are you repeating it? Will that solve the issue?

Comment: @AdrianLynch Nope, if I were to repeat it then the transparent part will be repeated too, which I only want it once at the top.

Comment: It seems to best thing to do it just make the background image stupidly long to cater for long content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this just by making the background image stupidly long instead.

Not a great option as I would prefer to keep image assets minimal, but it will do.